# Understanding P(X<Y+1) pmf to pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to show that:

$P(X < Y+1) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X < y+1 | Y = y)  f_Y(y) dy $

So far I used the following steps to show:

$P(X < Y+1) = \int_{y+1=-\infty}^\infty \int_{x=-\infty}^{y+1} f_{XY}(x,y) dxdy$

$P(X < Y+1) = \int_{y+1=-\infty}^\infty \int_{x=-\infty}^{y+1} f_{X|Y}(x|y) f_Y(y) dxdy$

$P(X < Y+1) = \int_{y+1=-\infty}^\infty P(X<y+1 | Y = y)  f_Y(y) dy$

I want to know if I am going along the correct lines and whether I have used any illegal steps? I am a bit confused about how to go from the second last step to the last step.

Please explain.

Comment: You should have $y = -\infty$ as the limit of your integration. Moreover it isn't needed to write $y = -\infty$ or $x=-\infty$, just simply $-\infty$. It is the term $dy$ or $dx$ that indicates what variable you integrate.

Comment: @DominikKutek thank you. Is this only the case in the final line due to how I only have one integral? I think I meant to remove dx in the final line. In the first two lines are the limits of integration fine?

Comment: It should be something like: $\mathbb P(X <Y+1) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{y+1} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{y+1} f_{(X|Y)}(x|y)f_Y(y)dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P(X<y+1 | Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$